# AxSU3D Android Facebook Plugin - "The parameter app_id is required"

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm using AxSU3D's Android plugin in a Unity project. When I try to use the Facebook Login method, I get an error that says "The parameter app_id is required"

I have posted my code below. I have REPLACED the string "fbAppID" with the actual ID. This is just the sample script that came with the plugin that I am trying to use.

Any help will be appreciated

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using AxSAndroidPlugin.Core;
using AxSAndroidPlugin.Social.Facebook;

public class FacebookSample : MonoBehaviour {

public string fbAppID = "YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID_HERE";

public GameObject picture;
//Texture2D tex;

void OnGUI () {

    if(GUI.Button(GUIControls.GetButtonRect(1), "Init" ))
        Facebook.Init(fbAppID);

    if(GUI.Button(GUIControls.GetButtonRect(2), "Login" ))
        Facebook.Login();

    if(GUI.Button(GUIControls.GetButtonRect(3), "IsLoggedIn"))
        Facebook.IsLoggedIn();

    if(GUI.Button(GUIControls.GetButtonRect(4), "User Info")) {
        Facebook.GetUserInfo();
    }

    if(GUI.Button(GUIControls.GetButtonRect(5), "Friends")) {
        Facebook.GetFriendsList();
    }

    if (GUI.Button (GUIControls.GetButtonRect (6), "Load Profile Picture")) {
        Facebook.LoadProfilePicture();
    }

    if (GUI.Button (GUIControls.GetButtonRect (7), "Get Profile Picture")) {
        Texture2D tex = Facebook.GetProfilePicture();
        picture.renderer.material.mainTexture = tex;
    }

    if(GUI.Button(GUIControls.GetButtonRect(8), "Send Request")) {
        Facebook.SendRequest("This Plugin Rocks!");
    }

    if(GUI.Button(GUIControls.GetButtonRect(9), "Post To Timeline")) {
        string name = "AxS Android Plugin";
        string caption = "AxS Android Plugin for Unity";
        string description = "A complete solution to all your Android native needs!";
        string link = "http://www.axsu3d.com/";
        string pictureLink = "http://www.axsu3d.com/DLs/axsu3dLogo.png";
        Facebook.PostToTimeline(name, caption, description, link, pictureLink);
    }

    //Get the user's likes
    if(GUI.Button(GUIControls.GetButtonRect(10), "User Likes")) {
        Facebook.GetUserLikes();
    }

    //Logout of Facebook
    if(GUI.Button(GUIControls.GetButtonRect(11), "Logout" ))
        Facebook.Logout();

    if(GUI.Button(GUIControls.GetButtonRect(12), "Back"))
        Application.LoadLevel("CoreSample");

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, wow. I didn't realize something I helped make would show up on SO.

The solution is quite simple, really. You probably did not use the "Merge Manifest" option.

You can find this option under "Tools/AxSU3D/Android/Merge Manifest". This will show a window where you can put in your Facebook app ID.

The option will create or merge a new AndroidManifest.xml file, which will also contain your Facebook App ID.

Try it out.